# React Jest test errors when using toHaveBeenNthCalledWith

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm following Jest's [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeennthcalledwithnthcall-arg1-arg2-) however I am not able to get around the following error. `expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith is not a function`

Unless I'm missing something, I am pretty certain that I have my `dummyFunction` setup correctly as a `jest.fn()`. I even consoled the output of `dummyFunction` just before I use it in my tests and this is the output.

**dummyFunction console.log output**

```
    { [Function: mockConstructor]
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function],
      mockReset: [Function],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
      mockReturnValue: [Function],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
      mockImplementation: [Function],
      mockReturnThis: [Function],
      mockRestore: [Function] }
```

**toHaveBeenCalledNthWith Test**

```
const dummyFunction = jest.fn();

expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // pass

expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, { foo: 'bar' }); // error
expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, { please: 'work' });
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Function name seems off, shouldn't it be `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` instead of `toHaveBeenCalledNthWith`?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying different things earlier and copied the wrong version. I'm having issues with it even with the correct spelling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` was released in `Jest` version [23.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2300) so you will see that error if you are using an earlier version of `Jest`.

Note that `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` is just [syntactic sugar for using `spy.mock.calls[nth]`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5605) so if you are using an earlier version of `Jest` you can just do the following:

```
const dummyFunction = jest.fn();

dummyFunction({ foo: 'bar' });
dummyFunction({ please: 'work' });

expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // pass

expect(dummyFunction.mock.calls[0]).toEqual([{ foo: 'bar' }]); // pass
expect(dummyFunction.mock.calls[1]).toEqual([{ please: 'work' }]); // pass
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, turns out I'm using Jest version 20.0.4. I appreciate you taking the time to show me how to work it on older versions.

Comment: @CWSites you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!